syntax error, unexpected string content "", expecting "-" or identifier or variable or number
In a PHP application I am trying to the users information from the table like below
session_start();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE company_id = $_SESSION['companyId']";
$result = $connect->query($sql);
but query statement in bold throws syntax error.
syntax error, unexpected string content "", expecting "-" or identifier or variable or number
Am I missing something?


Please use value bindings. This is open to sql injection.

First of all, you can't embed complex expressions in a string that way. You can use braces:
$string = "Some complex {$expression['value']}";

Or concatenation:
$string = "Some complex " . $expression['value'];

More importantly, writing a query like that leaves you open to SQL injection. This is a very dangerous way to write queries.
What you should do is use prepared statements to bind the parameters to your query, like this:
$statement = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE company_id = ?");

$statement->bind_param("i", $_SESSION['companyId']);

$result = $statement->execute();


Since PHP 8.2, one can do this in one step with execute_query(). See https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.execute-query.php

Try this :
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE company_id = " . $_SESSION['companyId'];

There are several ways to do this.

This is vulnerable to SQL injection. Read the other answer.
